# c-select() identify first fd that unblocked select for read/recv operation

Tags: c

Given list of Client FDs (eg: 98,99,100) and data is received on FD 99, 100 at the same time 
Select unblocks and read FDs contains FD:99 and FD: 100

How to determine, which is the first FD on which data has come first??

If I check serially through the list of client FD's that I have in my array it will always try to do socket read on FD: 99. But my application must read the data from FD : 100 as data is received on that FD first.

```
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(98, &readfds);
FD_SET(99, &readfds);
FD_SET(100, &readfds);
gMaxfd=100;
rc = select(gMaxfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(rc>0){
    /* Handle the fds for read operation */
    /* Here how to identify which is the first FD on which recv has to be called first ???*/
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which is better than `select` (google for *C10K problem*); and why do you care about which fd has the oldest data?

Comment: You should explain much more about what your application is doing, and what application-level protocol (what kind of messages and exchanges) you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If there was any significant delay between the events that made those file descriptors readable, `select` would have returned with the first one without waiting for the second one. So if you get multiple fds, you should treat the events as happening simultaneously.

If simultaneous messages from different sources break your higher-level protocol, you need to redesign it.

Comment: If the protocol can receive data on UDP or TCP sockets, how to make co-relation on which FD data is received first ?
Eg: Packet 1 , Received over UDP , FD : 99 select unblocks
    immediately two more Packets , 
    Packet 2, Received over TCP , FD: 100 and 
    Packet 3, received over UDP, FD : 99
In this case, my application or protocol analyser must read data from FD 100 as it has come first, if i do seqential search i will end up LIFO instead of FIFO. 
Please suggest how or what kind of redesign can be done without knowing FD on which data is received earlier?

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement some [round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) scheduling. So use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and remember the previously processed file descriptor. BTW, as [answered by Wumpus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26016273/841108) your multiplexing syscall (`poll` or `select` ...) will usually give one (or a few) readable file descriptors.

Alternatively, read from *all* the readable file descriptors before restarting your [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)

Notice that both UDP and TCP are byte oriented, without any notion of message packet (at application level). See [ip(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), [udp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html), [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), [Internet Protocol Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite),  and remember that [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is only a byte stream *without* any packet or message boundaries at application level: a given single [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) on one end can be on the other side gotten thru *several* [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) (or vice versa several `send` can be coalesced into one `recv` etc...). Your application has to *buffer* and your protocol has to *define* the message *boundaries*. Routers between emitter and receiver are allowed to -and do- chunk and join data "packets" at will and at random!

Comment: If the protocol can receive data on UDP or TCP sockets, how to make co-relation on which FD data is received first ?
Eg: Packet 1 , Received over UDP , FD : 99 select unblocks
    immediately two more Packets , 
    Packet 2, Received over TCP , FD: 100 and 
    Packet 3, received over UDP, FD : 99
In this case, my application or protocol analyser must read data from FD 100 as it has come first, if i do seqential search i will end up LIFO instead of FIFO. 
Please suggest how or what kind of redesign can be done without knowing FD on which data is received earlier?

Comment: Your protocol is then badly designed. Have each message contain some unique ID.

Comment: You should explain much more the application protocol you are using. I guess that it is very wrong.

Comment: Sip protocol uses both udp n tcp sockets. client can receive requests on any of the sockets so in this case sip protocol as per 3261 is wrongly designed?